# eigenvalues of $AB$ are eigenvalues of $\sqrt{B} A \sqrt{B}$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose $A,B$ are symmetric positive definite matrices. An author claims that the spectrum of $AB$ is the spectrum of $\sqrt{B}A\sqrt{B}$. Why?

Certainly they have the same trace by cyclic permutation. And they have the same determinant by multiplicativity.

Ideas: Maybe use the minimax principle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that

$$AB = B^{-1/2} (B^{1/2} A B^{1/2}) B^{1/2},$$

so these two are similar.

Answer (score 4):

$AB$ is similar to $\sqrt{B} (AB) \sqrt{B}^{-1} = \sqrt{B} A \sqrt{B}$.